# (Python) Why not import modules in function instead of at the beginning and best way to import them?

Tags: python, function, import, module

I am writing a program in python. I am using about a dozen modules. Currently I have placed them in the functions themselves. My reasoning is that since a user is not going to use all the functions in a session, many modules don't have to be imported uselessly until a function requires them. But all the code I have seen till now have their imports at the beginning. What are their reasons and advantages?

Also what is the best way to import ? I have seen several types like:

1. `from tkinter import *` and then `Label()`, `Tk()`
2. `import tkinter`        and then `tkinter.Label()`, `tkinter.Tk()`
3. `import tkinter as tk`  and then `tk.Label()`?

What's the best way? I see first one is shortest. Is it also the best?

Comment: @martijn-pieters that answer is very good for the first part of my question. i consider first part of the question answered. its second part remains unanswered though. shall i remove this post and create a new thread or edit post to contain second part only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to answer the second part of your question.

1. `from tkinter import *` and then `Label()`,`Tk()`
   This is considerd bad practice, because it mixes the namespaces and can confuse future readers of your code. For example, many modules have a `sqrt` function (the standard library `math`, `numpy`, `scipy`). If you use import all (`*`) for several of them, the last one will win. Sometimes a module has functions which will overwrite standard python functions, and the reader cannot know where this specific function comes from. Even if you only use import-all on one module, the reader has to differentiate between standard python functions and the package functions, e.g. is `getint` from `tkinter`? why did he use `NONE` instead of `None` etc.. This should only be used for interactive work on the interpreter.
2. `import tkinter` and then `tkinter.Label()`, `tkinter.Tk()`
   This is the most explicit (and do remember that  [explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)), but it is a bit long.
3. `import tkinter as tk` and then `tk.Label()`?
   This one is a good compromise between 1 and 2. Short but explicit.

So you have to decide between 2 and 3. If you use the package often, and it has a clear short name, (such as `tkinter -> tk`, `numpy -> np`) I would use the short name.

Comment: I believe I somewhere (effbot.org and webpage linking there) read that tkinter was designed to be imported as `from tkinter import *` without problems but since I can't find that post and since I read many other posts that are against such import, I accept your answer.

Comment: @love_in_dreams: there's no way to design any python package to be imported this way without causing problems. The very nature of importing things into a global scope will *always* have the potential for problems. Tkinter is particularly susceptible since people often use tkinter and ttk together, and they both have classes named Button, Label, etc.

Comment: ok thanks to you both. we are all too lazy i guess because i don't see many people/examples using the correct way. Using shortname indeed seems like the best way, for production code anyway.